# Как произвести авторизацию к API docdoc.ru посредством PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

Здравствуйте! Я новичок, и мне не понятно кое что по PHP, в частности помогите мне разобраться с тем, как осуществляется авторизация к API другого сервиса посредством PHP, в частности пример это сайт docdoc.ru и потом как эти данные вывести на другом сайте? Вот документация API: https://vk.cc/6broIS Обычно в некоторых партнерках приводят пример кода, а тут ничего нет. Заранее вам благодарен. Просто больше не знаю куда обратиться.

Comment: Там обработка JSON идет. что там не понятного может быть, даже не знаю.

Comment: Просто нужен хоть какой-то визуальный пример как это делать.

Comment: Что конкретно не получается и что вы пробовали сделать? Там ничего сложного нет, всё прекрасно описано: примеры запросов есть, получаемые значения есть. Получили, JSON вперёд и с песней.

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю как это реализовать в PHP. Вот в чем проблема. Хотел просто на wordpress сайт подгрузить список врачей с кнопкой для записи/

Comment: Берут cms, ищут плагины и жмут "установить", а потом называют себя программистами. Вам на php.net нужно идти и там пользоваться поиском. Благо, почти вся документация на русский переведена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://LOGIN:PASSWORD@back.docdoc.ru/api/rest/1.0.4/json/metro/city/1/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$page = json_decode($page);
//print_r($page);

foreach($page->MetroList as $val){
 echo $val->Id.'<br />';
}
```